# Docker secrets in ELK stack

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, elastic-stack, docker-swarm

I have been struggling for the last few days to set up the ELK stack on Docker. I would appreciate your help.

### Problem

`docker-compose.yml` file that I'm using is from [the official repo](https://github.com/elastic/stack-docs/blob/main/docs/en/getting-started/docker/docker-compose.yml)

Instead of using `.env` file for sensitive data such as passwords or API keys, I'm trying to use [Docker secrets](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/). However, unfortunately, the official image of `elasticsearch:8.0.0` does not provide `_FILE` postfix for its environment variables (e.g. `ELASTIC_PASSWORD_FILE`).

After some research, I found [this Medium article](https://medium.com/@basi/docker-environment-variables-expanded-from-secrets-8fa70617b3bc) where the author shows a trick how to "expand" env variables from Docker secrets. Basically, to turn:

`ELASTIC_PASSWORD={{DOCKER-SECRET:elk-elastic-password}}` into `ELASTIC_PASSWORD=pass4elastic`

Considering that our Docker secret has the name `elk-elastic-password` and content `pass4elastic`. To use it, the author recommends adding the `env_secrets_expand.sh` script file to container ENTRYPOINT and invoking it with `source env_secrets_expand.sh`.

I noticed that overriding the default ENTRYPOINT of the `elasticsearch:8.0.0` image is not a good idea as it doesn't behave correctly. Instead, I've tried to "extend" it by creating my own `docker-entrypoint.sh` where I will first expand env variables and second call parent entrypoint script.

### Files & testing setup

**docker-compose.yml**

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  setup:
    build: .
    secrets:
      - elk-elastic-password
    environment:
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD={{DOCKER-SECRET:elk-elastic-password}}

secrets:
  elk-elastic-password:
    file: ./elk-elastic-password.txt
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.0.0

COPY env_secrets_expand.sh /env_secrets_expand.sh
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

**docker-entrypoint.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/bash

source /env_secrets_expand.sh

exec /bin/tini -- /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh "$@"
```

**docker-entrypoint.sh**
Same as in [the original repo](https://gist.github.com/bvis/b78c1e0841cfd2437f03e20c1ee059fe#file-env_secrets_expand-sh)

All the files are also located in [my testing repo](https://github.com/marcin-wlodarczyk/elk-secrets)

### Steps to reproduce

```sh
docker compose build
docker compose up -d

docker exec -it elk-secrets-setup-1 bash

# In container

printenv | grep ELASTIC_PASSWORD
# output: ELASTIC_PASSWORD={{DOCKER-SECRET:elk-elastic-password}} (Incorrect)

# After manually "expanding" vars: 

source /env_secrets_expand.sh
printenv | grep ELASTIC_PASSWORD
# output: ELASTIC_PASSWORD=pass4elastic (Correct)
```

### Conclusions

Expansion of variables in `docker-entrypoint.sh` doesn't affect variables inside the container. However, calling `docker-entrypoint.sh` manually has the correct effect.

My main objective is to replace `.env` with `docker secrets` I would appreciate it if you could provide fixes to my current approach or suggest something better.

Comment: I may have missed it, what's the question?

Comment: I'm trying to replace `.env` file with docker secrets, but the presented approach is not working correctly.

Comment: Have you figured this out? I guess the best would be to create a PR for Elastic to include these expansions for secrets. The problem is that there is no unified name for such secrets … you probably shouldn't use the `elastic` user's password anyway. For Kibana, use the service account token. For Logstash, it's more complicated, since each pipeline could use its own user. Hence, a generic `_FILE` expansion would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

My task was similar; I wanted to map the `ELASTICSEARCH_SERVICEACCOUNTTOKEN` variable, which contains the token that Kibana should use to connect to Elasticsearch.

I solved this by using the following entrypoint, which achieves a similar thing to yours – it can expand arbitrary environment variables based on their `_FILE` counterparts:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

: "${ENV_SECRETS_DIR:=/run/secrets}"

env_secret_debug()
{
    if [ -n "$ENV_SECRETS_DEBUG" ]; then
        echo "$@"
    fi
}

# expand known _FILE overrides
for env_var in \
    ELASTICSEARCH_SERVICEACCOUNTTOKEN
    do
    file_env_var="${env_var}_FILE"
    secret_file=$(printenv "$file_env_var")
    if [ -n "$secret_file" ]; then
        env_secret_debug "Expanding $env_var from contents of $secret_file"
        if [ -f "$secret_file" ]; then
            export "${env_var}=$(cat "$secret_file")"
        else
            echo "Error in entrypoint.sh: File '$secret_file' mapped by $env_var does not exist or is not readable!"
        fi
        unset $file_env_var
    fi
done

exec /bin/tini -- /usr/local/bin/kibana-docker "$@"
```

Note the actual executable for Kibana is `/usr/local/bin/kibana-docker` – the original entrypoint does not really do more than that.

The entrypoint can expand the environment variable `ELASTICSEARCH_SERVICEACCOUNTTOKEN` based on the contents of the `ELASTICSEARCH_SERVICEACCOUNTTOKEN_FILE` environment variable, which you can point to a mounted secrets file.

My corresponding Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:8.1.1
USER root
COPY --chown=1000:0 entrypoint.sh /usr/share/kibana/entrypoint.sh
USER kibana
ENTRYPOINT [ "/usr/share/kibana/entrypoint.sh" ]
```

Here's the snipped from the respective compose file:

```yaml
kibana:
  build:
    - ./kibana_test_file:/run/secrets/kibana_test_file:ro
  environment:
    ELASTICSEARCH_SERVICEACCOUNTTOKEN_FILE: /run/secrets/kibana_test_file
    ENV_SECRETS_DEBUG: 1
```

Now, this adds some maintenance effort. But you can find the original Dockerfiles here: https://github.com/elastic/dockerfiles